# On the elementary proof of Dirichlet theorem on arithmetic progressions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

In [Cassels, JWS, Rational quadratic forms, p. 333], the autor says: "In fact the elementary proof of Dirichlet's theorem [Selberg (1949)] makes essential use of the existence of genera".
In reviewing that Selberg's paper I can't find where the existence of genera is used. Could anyone help me about that subject?

Comment: Perhaps it is used implicitly in the study of (4.2) in the course of proving Lemma 1?